# Why do source code uninstaller scripts “cd” into the directory before deleting a file?

Tags: linux, command-line, uninstall

So I have had to uninstall some command line tools I have compiled from source on macOS Sierra (10.12.2) and noticed these similarly structured commands returned in the Terminal when I run `sudo make uninstall`:

Output of `sudo make uninstall` for HTop:

```
( cd '/usr/local/share/applications' && rm -f htop.desktop )
( cd '/usr/local/bin' && rm -f htop )
( cd '/usr/local/share/man/man1' && rm -f htop.1 )
( cd '/usr/local/share/pixmaps' && rm -f htop.png )
```

Output of `sudo make uninstall` for MTR:

```
( cd '/usr/local/share/man/man8' && rm -f mtr.8 )
( cd '/usr/local/sbin' && rm -f mtr )
```

Output of `sudo make uninstall` for SSHPASS:

```
( cd '/usr/local/bin' && rm -f sshpass )
( cd '/usr/local/share/man/man1' && rm -f sshpass.1 )
```

It seems odd to me that each command is essentially `cd`ing into a directory and then running `rm -f` in conjunction with that `cd` command. Why not just `rm -f` the file directly with the full path like this; using the SSHPASS output here for example:

```
rm -f '/usr/local/bin/sshpass'
rm -f '/usr/local/share/man/man1/sshpass.1'
```

I understand the need to be safe when manually typing out a command like this, but in the case of a preset script—where the process itself should be clean and risk free—what is the benefit of the make script removing items as a compound command?

Comment: Possibly a side effect of the way the Makefile is organized: Directory and file information probably comes from different sources, and it's simpler to let `cd` handle the directory and process the file afterwards. First step to find out is to look at the Makefile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can only think that this because of a mistake that was once made in the past.

Basically someone accidentally inserted an extra space into a file path, and deleted it; see [this commit on GitHub for example](https://github.com/MrMEEE/bumblebee-Old-and-abbandoned/commit/a047be85247755cdbe0acce6f1dafc8beb84f2ac#diff-3fbb47e318cd8802bd325e7da9aaabe8L351).

By doing `cd '/usr/local/share/man/man8' && rm -f mtr.8` - if the first part of the command, the `cd` fails, it will never run the `rm -f` at all. It’s a fail safe.